# JavaFX with WebSwing: Session Ended

Tags: java, javafx, browser, webswing

I'm trying to deploy my JavaFX application to web browser with WebSwing. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKFJEfBBpKI and official tutorial on  WebSwing site. I added my application, but when I try to run it I get an error:

```
Your session has ended. You may start a new session or close your browser window.
```

Can I do something about it? Or is there any other, easy way to run my application in web browser? I tried Java Web Start, but it didn't work. Do I need any plug-ins or should I change browser? I'm trying to run it on Chrome.

Comment: Can you please attach full logs and version of webswing you are running? This seems like a configuration issue, maybe there is some library missing on the classpath. You don't need any plugins to run Webswing and it runs in all major browsers.